# How to avoid Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors using precintcon package in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df,with monthly rainfall

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   396 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ year         : int  1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 ...
 $ month        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ stn1         : int  2 42 91 267 482 1282 1207 982 705 259 ...
 $ stn2         : int  0 9 23 61 68 151 196 73 172 59 ...
 $ stn3         : int  0 10 34 52 122 258 349 237 140 154 …
```

I want to calculate Rainfall Anomaly Index (rai) for all the station (stn1, stn2, stn3,....).
I used the following code:

```
library(precintcon)
rai(df, granularity = "m")
```

However it gives the following error

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

But when I use it for only one station it works

```
rai(df[1:3], granularity = "m") #calculating rai for one only station
```

How can I calculate rai for all the station at once without any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution, not far form the solution proposed by @RonakShah :

```
num_stations <- 3
rais <-  lapply(1:num_stations, function(k) {
   dfk <- df[,c(1,2,k+2)]
   rai(dfk, granularity = "m")
})

# Plot rai of the first station
plot(rais[[1]])
```

Answer (score 3):

`rai` function seems to need daily or monthly precipitation series, so 1st two columns are fixed. We can get all the columns which start with `"stn1"` and use them in `rai` function.

```
cols <- grep('^stn1', names(df))
output <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = c('year', 'month')), 
      lapply(cols, function(x) precintcon::rai(df[c(1:2, x)], granularity = "m")))
```

Comment: I had the same idea but your code is simpler. And you beat me by seconds :(. Upvote.